# Print out how many times to calculate the sum of the squares of its digits until answer is 1 or 4

Tags: function-construction, infinite-loop

I am trying to write a recursive function, toscare1[], that takes as parameter a positive natural number. Then calculate the sum of the squares of its digits, thus creating a new number; then, we repeat the procedure on this new number, etc., until one of the following cases happens: the sum becomes 1 or becomes 4. Then, the function should return the number of times we performed the procedure.
This is what I have tried so far

```
toscare1[n_] := {
  For[i = 0, 
   NestWhile[ne = Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2] &, n, ne == 1 || ne == 4],
    i++, Print[i]]
  }
```

Comment: You are quite close. `f[n_] := {Length@# - 1, #} &@
  NestWhileList[Plus @@ (IntegerDigits[#]^2) &, n, # != 1 && # != 4 &]` Usage: e.g., `f[2331]`

Comment: Maybe closer to your original but similar to Syed:   toscare1[n_] := 
 Length[NestWhileList[(Total[IntegerDigits[#]^2]) &, 
    n, (! (# == 1 || # == 4)) &]] - 1

Answer (score 3):

Syed's comment has priority, but I thought it would be useful to provide a bit of flavor. Before jumping to a one-liner, it's often useful (and easier) to break the problem up into smaller functions. You know how to do a single step in your calculation, so start by turning that into a function:

```
toscareStep[int_Integer] := Total[IntegerDigits[int]^2]
```

`toscareStep[2331]` gives `23`.

At this point, you could build your own recursion, but Mathematica has several nice functions for repeated application: Nest, NestList, NestWhile, NestWhileList, FixedPoint, FixedPointList.

For example, `NestList[toscareStep, 2331, 10]` gives `{2331, 23, 13, 10, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}`. This looks promising, because you can count the members of the list.

You want to terminate on a condition, so use the While version.

```
NestWhileList[toscareStep, 2331, (# != 4 && # != 1) &]
```

gives `{2331, 23, 13, 10, 1}`

To get the "number of times we performed the procedure", we need to take Length - 1, because the first element of NestWhileList was the input (i.e. no steps performed yet at that point). So,

```
toscareStepCount[int_Integer] := 
  -1 + Length[NestWhileList[toscareStep, int, (# != 4 && # != 1) &]]
```

For example, `toscareStepCount[2331]` gives `4`. This approach "throws away" the record of each step, and that record is often useful. So, you might want something more like this:

```
toscareStepList[int_Integer] := NestWhileList[toscareStep, int, (# != 4 && # != 1) &];
toscareStepCount[int_Integer] := -1 + toscareStepList[int]
```

If you wanted to build your own recursive implementation, the typical way to do something like this is to use an accumulator (in this case a simple counter):

```
toscareStepCount[val_Integer] := toscareStepCount[val, 0];
toscareStepCount[1, count_Integer] := count;
toscareStepCount[4, count_Integer] := count;
toscareStepCount[current_Integer, count_Integer] := 
  toscareStepCount[toscareStep[current], 1 + count]
```